# Вероятность того, что 4 случайных человека проголосовали за один вариант

Tags: математика, теория-вероятностей, вычислительный-эксперимент

Какова вероятность того, что 4 **абсолютно случайно** взятых человека проголосовали за одного кандидата, если список кандидатов с результатами (в пример взяты выборы 2019 года на Украине, вы можете взять любые другие данные) таков:

```
1 — 32,1%  # Кандидат 1
2 — 17,1%  # Кандидат 2
3 — 12,5%  # ..........
4 — 10,4%
5 — 6,9%
6 — 5,7%
```

Comment: Сумма четвёртых степеней всех вероятностей, если мне не изменяет память.

Comment: А это ничего, что у вас сумма процентов - 84,7%? :)

Comment: @Harry, накинул для примера. Там большой список просто)

Comment: Да лишь бы не 146%... :) Просто при этом вопрос в том, считать ли, если все проголосуют "против всех", как "проголосовали за одного кандидата" или нет...

Comment: @Harry, ну, если все проголосуют за одного — можно и не считать, конечно) Была интересна именно вон та вероятность. Кстати, не могли бы в конечный ответ добавить саму вероятность в процентах? А то я либо слишком далёк от математики (что вероятнее), либо я недооценил слишком размер этих процентов)

Comment: Добавил прямо в ответ.

Comment: @Harry, спасибо огромное! Ну я и дегенерат конечно))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

По логике - события для каждого кандидата взаимоисключающие, события для четырех избирателей - независимые.

Вероятность, что первый проголосовал за кандидата i - p_i. Вероятность, что все 4 за него -(p_i)^4.

Ну, а дальше надо просто просуммировать все варианты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух"*

P.S. Вычислительный эксперимент подтверждает :)

P.P.S. Для приведенных данных, если рассматривать совпадения *только* за кандидатов (если все четверо голосуют против всех - считаем, что они голосуют против разных всех :)), искомая вероятность составляет около 1.2%.